# Make selfcontained browser app?

Tags: android, iphone, url, browser, widget

Is there a easy way to create an Android and/or/both IPhone app that lunches any or specific browser and goes to specified URL ?
I want to make it, so it look like an app ..i.e. installed as widget or app ..

Any pointers to documentation are welcome too ?
I would prefer if no coding is necessary :), but is OK if it is needed.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yup http://cordova.apache.org

Refer to the link and follow the hello world tutorials... Very useful for your purpose.